Exiting out of a java shutdown hook
I have a program that processes database entries. I added a shutdown hook to the program to write a dump file in case of every exit so I know on where to proceed in the database in case of an early shutdown. So it looks something like this:
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // write the dumpfile here
        }
    });

Till now everything looks/works fine. But as I was about to implement the writing of the dumpfile I need to handle the case, if the dumpfile can not be created/written to. So I was fiddling around and tried to just print a message, that the dumpfile is not writable and tried to exit out completely by using System.exit(); but I ran into an interesting behaviour: if you exit out of a program via System.exit inside a shutdown hook, the program keeps running. I guess it is as you exit the exit routine and therefore the exit is never completed?
So this results in the program keep printing to stdout:
package com.ffleuchten.Test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("shutdown hook running!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
        
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread alive!");
        }
    }
}

this results in:
Thread alive!
^Cshutdown hook running!
Thread alive!
Thread alive!
^CThread alive!
^C^C^CThread alive!
Thread alive!
Thread alive!
Thread alive!
Thread alive!

The ^C marks the points in time, where I pressed ctrl+c to stop the program. As you can see I can not stop the program by pressing ctrl+c anymore, so at this point you'll need to kill the process via OS.
Now I was wondering on how is one supposed to exit out of a shutdown hook early properly, or are you supposed to complete the shutdown hook in every case?

Why do you have to do anything? Just let that method do nothing (with early return; or whatever). Other completely unrelated shutdown hooks might want to do their own cleanup. It seems overzealous to try to prevent them from doing their cleanup, just because unrelated cleanup failed.

System.exit within a shutdown hook causing the program to keep running is surprising to me as well, and I can reproduce that behaviour locally.

In my use case I let the hook simply complete. So no issues there. I was just wondering about that behaviour with the system.exit

Yeah, so, this question breaks down into two unrelated points. [1] How do I exit out of a shutdown hook (and the answer there is a disappointing: You don't - your JVM is already exiting. The other shut down hooks have already run or are already running as far as you know. Just.. do not do the thing you can't do, is all. replace logTheStuff() with if (writable) logTheStuff() in your shutdown hook, and separately, [B] WTF is up with java just crashing the shutdown procedure if you invoke .exit in the middle of it? Which is, indeed, weird. File a bug. But stop doing it.

Don't call System.exit in the shutdown hook. System.exit doesn't return until all of the shutdown hooks have finished...but you're calling it in a shutdown hook.

"I was just wondering about that behaviour with the system.exit". This issue was 2nd google result for "system.exit inside shutdown hook". Seems they've decided it's not an issue.

"This is all working as designed." I see. TIL I guess :D

maybe the secret is (partly) documented for exit(): "... and then blocks indefinitely. This method neither returns nor throws an exception; that is, it does not complete either normally or abruptly." - so apparently calling exit() is blocking the shutdown itself... also from addShutdownHook(): "... Shutdown hooks should also finish their work quickly. ..."

kind of reminds me of creating an instance inside its own constructor...

This is explicitly documented for System.exit(int) since Java 20: "Because this method always blocks indefinitely, if it is invoked from a shutdown hook, it will prevent that shutdown hook from terminating. Consequently, this will prevent the shutdown sequence from finishing."

@MarkRotteveel That is the doc for Runtime.exit. The System.exit does refer to that method, though

@Michael Right, mixed them because they are basically the same thing :)

This question is not "clear AF". Just because somebody answered it and you found that answer acceptable doesn't mean your question is clear. What does it have to do with databases? What does it have to do with a dump file? It seems to boil down to "Why doesn't my application exit if I call System.exit(1) from a shutdown hook?" That is part of the clarity, you have a bunch of information that makes your question sound like it has some greater meaning or concept, but it doesn't.

The docs don't spell it out. The source code is pretty clear, though. shutdown threads are, as the name suggests, run in separate threads. Whilst waiting for each thread to finish, the JVM is in the middle of the code that controls this (in the class java.lang.Shutdown).. specifically, holding a lock. So when your shutdown thread also calls it, you've got an instant deadlock:

Your System.exit() call is stuck waiting for the lock to release.
The thread that holds the lock will not relinquish it until all shutdown threads have completed.

Thus, neither will ever finish and the process is deadlocked.
conclusion: Calling System.exit in a shutdown hook always does this. That's the last call that thread is ever going to make, and the shutdown process never completes.
NB: As to answer your actual question "how do I do that", the answer is: You do not. The JVM is already shutting down. So, if your intent is 'my shutdown thread should not do anything further' just return, or simply don't do the thing (use if, for example). If your intent is: "I also want other shutdown threads to not run / stop running", you can't. You have no control over ordering (you can't make a shutdown hook that runs before the others and has the option to stop the others from running), and you can't just abort running threads. They're already running, as far as you know they're already finished. You can't travel back in time.
If you have a bunch of shutdown hooks that should not run if this fails or should not run until this 'write out some logs' step is complete, you need to make a little framework where you register this 'must run first and if it aborts none of the others should run' thing, and all the 'these must run afterwards and only if the logging step completed', and that whole thing is a single shutdown hook.

Hint¹ from documentation of exit(): "... and then blocks indefinitely. This method neither returns nor throws an exception; that is, it does not complete either normally or abruptly."  |-| ¹ its not the real problem (the lock) but still an indication that it will block the hook anyway

@user85421 Since Java 20 it is documented explicitly: "Because this method always blocks indefinitely, if it is invoked from a shutdown hook, it will prevent that shutdown hook from terminating. Consequently, this will prevent the shutdown sequence from finishing."

Thanks to @rzwitserloot for this great explanation/answer. I understood the problem and will find  other ways to solve my issue than using additional System.exit calls.
To the guy closing the question: What do you mean "needs detail or clarity?" The question was clear af and even got mutliple answers within a day. So I guess the question can not be that bad on clarity. Besides that: what do you want for additional Information? The given information is basically the same as in the official bug description linked by Michael. So it is enough to fix the bug, but not enough for SO? I guess so...
